# Gerar UML do código PHP

Tags: php, uml

Existe algum software, de preferencia opensource, que gere o UML de um código já escrito em PHP?

O chato é ter que atualizar o diagrama toda vez que o código é atualizado.

Comment: Cara, dê uma olhada nesse [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/doc/index.html), nunca usei mas creio que pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: O ruim nesse BOUML é que é pago

Comment: Há várias opções na internet. rs
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6025-PHP-Generate-UML-diagrams-from-PHP-code-using-GraphML.html

Comment: Você pode usar o 'Case UML'. Ele pode suportar PHP e outros linguagem de programação.
Pode visitar o site pra mais informação: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/free-use-case-tool/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInarEk-mu4AIVjByGCh1knwaREAAYASAAEgKgJPD_BwE

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [PHP_UML](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML)

- Permite gerar arquivos UML/XMI versão 1.4, ou 2.1
- Gera uma documentação em HTML
- Pode gerar esqueletos de código PHP baseado em um arquivo UML/XMI
- Pode converter arquivos UML/XMI da versão 1.4 para 2.1

Para instalar via linha de comando é necessário o PEAR. Caso não o possua [instale](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) e depois execute no terminal:

```
pear install pear/php_uml
```

Para gerar via terminal basta utilizar o comando

```
phpuml [INPUT] -n [PROJECT NAME] -o [OUTPUT LOCATION] -f [OUTPUT FORMAT]
```

No exemplo a seguir, o PHP_UML irá percorrer todos os arquivos em `/var/www/foo` e exportar o arquivo `/var/tmp/MyProject.xmi` nomeando o projeto como MyProject.

```
phpuml /var/www/foo -n MyProject -o /var/tmp/
```

Para mais comando verifique a [documentação](http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/package.php.php-uml.command-line.php)

Outra maneira de gerar é criar utilizar a [API](http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/package.php.php-uml.api.php) criando um script PHP. Por exemplo:

```
// Seta o caminho padrão de inclusão de arquivo como sendo a pasta do PEAR
set_include_path( '/usr/lib/php/pear/' );
require_once __DIR__ . '/uml/UML.php';

$uml = new PHP_UML();   
// Define qual pasta ou arquivos serão parseados
$uml->setInput('/var/www/foo');
// Realiza o parser e seta o nome do projeto como MyProject
$uml->parse('MyProject');
// Ignora alguns arquivos que contenha um padrão de nome
$uml->setIgnorePatterns('.svn');
$uml->export('xmi', '/var/tmp/');
```

Veja mais [exemplos](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_PHP_UML__PHP_UML-1.6.1examplestest_to_run.php.html) na [documentação da API](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/docs/latest/)